# Filter list with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I think this is a easy task but I'm new to regex so can't figure it out. I want to filter a list that contains something like this:  "ANY"-"ANY"-"ANY"

Input:

```
List1 = ["AB.22-01-01", "AB.33-01-44", "--4", "AA.44--05", "--"]
```

Output:

```
List2 = ["AB.22-01-01", "AB.33-01-44"]
```

Each item will contain two "-" but I only want to get the ones with text on each sides of the "-".

Comment: And what regular expressions have you tried? Maybe you don't even need a regular expression. Why not use `filter(lambda x: len(x.split('-')) == 3 and all(x.split('-')), List1)`?

Comment: And @Maciek solution is a lot faster; 160ns versus 1.52us for regex  match and 1.43us for filter+regex

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this using [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) :

```
import re

p = re.compile('^.+-.+-.+$')
l1 = ["AB.22-01-01", "AB.33-01-44", "--4", "AA.44--05", "--"]
l2 = [ s for s in l1 if p.match(s) ]
```

Comment: The one that was most understandable (for me) and over twice as fast as some of the other solutions (Did not try all) with a list of 100+ items

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regular expressions. It will return all element that don't contains `--`

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'^((?!--).)*$')
>>> [i for i in List1 if pat.match(i)]
['AB.22-01-01', 'AB.33-01-44']
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rM8tM5/1)</kbd>