# Finding the name of a method in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to figure this out: how the method of an object is named, in case if I remember vaguely how it could be named.

For example, currently I use this approach quite often, this certainly helps me to find the correct name of the method (set_size_inches) in case I remembered 'set_size', however, in case if I had 'inches' in my mind, then this approach would not work

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> fig = plt.gcf()
>>> [fn for fn in dir(fig) if fn.startswith('set_size')]
['set_size_inches']
>>> [fn for fn in dir(fig) if fn.startswith('inches')]
[]
```

Any straightforward easy approach to make it working for text in-between the Method-name?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `... if "inches" in fn]`?

Comment: Thanks, :) yeah, it is easy and straightforward and does the magic!!

Comment: You can also use a regex filter for `".*inches.*"` to filter `dir(fig)`. See [Filter list with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960334/filter-list-with-regex).